# Fazendo com que um input só apareça quando um option(select) for escolhido

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um formulário de cadastro, com um selected, mas uma das opções desse selected quando selecionada deveria aparecer um input.
Exemplo:

```
<select>
    <option>value1</option>
    <option>value2</option>
</select>

<input type="text" style="display:none" />
```

quando fosse escolhida a opção 2. aparecesse o input(display:block)

Alguém sabe como fazer isso? obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, dê um `id` ao seu `select` para que possamos trabalhar com ele no javascript.

Depois, você pode colocar seu `input` dentro de uma `div` e exibi-la ou oculta-la de acordo com o option selecionado.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inputOculto').hide();
  $('#mySelect').change(function() {
    if ($('#mySelect').val() == 'value2') {
      $('#inputOculto').show();
    } else {
      $('#inputOculto').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>value1</option>
  <option>value2</option>
</select>
<div id="inputOculto">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Certinho amigo! Muito Obrigado!