# Problema com JS e id que só funcionam com o primeiro id utilizado

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Não sou desenvolvedor profissional, mas como em qualquer local de trabalho, o suporte técnico faz tudo.

Me foi pedido para criar uma página de suporte à equipe de vendas externa, onde possam incluir informações sobre o cliente em questão.
Nesse caso, são incluídas informações simples, como:
Produto X, tem no local? SIM ou NÃO. Caso sim, apareça o campo para inserir o valor praticado pelo cliente.

Eu encontrei aqui no [site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96884/fazendo-com-que-um-input-s%C3%B3-apare%C3%A7a-quando-um-optionselect-for-escolhido), uma resposta que me ajudou muito com isso. Segue o código que utilizei:

```
PRODUTO X: <select name="produtox" id="valor_sim" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
        <option value="SIM">SIM</option>
        <option value="NÃO">NÃO</option>
      </select><br>
      
      <div id="inputOculto">
        VALOR INTENSE: <input name="produtox_valor" id="valor_sim" type="number" min="0" max="9999"><br>
      </div>
```

Esse é o código do JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inputOculto').hide();
    $('#valor_sim').change(function() {
      if ($('#valor_sim').val() == 'SIM') {
        $('#inputOculto').show();
      } else {
        $('#inputOculto').hide();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Até aqui tudo bem, o código funciona perfeitamente. O problema, é que nos próximos produtos, isso não funciona neles, somente no primeiro. Pesquisei um pouco, e vi que poderia ser por conta do id ser o mesmo para todos, e encontrei uma resposta sobre usar a opção **this** [nesse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485588/como-fazer-com-que-v%c3%a1rios-elementos-participem-do-event-listener), mas como não compreendo o uso e não sei se seria o caso de utilizá-lo, peço a ajuda nessa situação.

Obrigado.

Comment: +1 por ter pesquisado e posto os links da pergunta, isso é um colirio para os olhos, muito bom :) ah, aqui o suporte não mexe no código :D

Comment: Obrigado. Já busquei muita informação por aqui, e sempre ajudou muito ter os links. Abraços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta passando por esse problema justamente por usar o `id`, o id é funciona como um identificador único, por isso não pode repeti-lo, pois apenas a primeira ocorrência é "válida", as outras serão ignoradas.

Para isso existe o atributo `class` que serve para você classificar os elementos, e este atributo permite receber diversas classes(classificadores).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var produtoX = $('#produto-x');
  var produtoY = $('#produto-y');
  
  inicializarProduto(produtoX);
  inicializarProduto(produtoY);

});

function inicializarProduto(produto) {
  var valorProduto = produto.find('.valor-produto');
  valorProduto.hide();
  produto.find('.seletor-produto').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'SIM') {
      valorProduto.show();
    } else {
      valorProduto.hide()
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="produto-x" class="linha-produto">
      Produto X:
      <select name="produto-x" class="seletor-produto" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
        <option value="SIM">SIM</option>
        <option value="NÃO">NÃO</option>
      </select>

      <div class="valor-produto">
        VALOR INTENSE: 
        <input name="produto-x_valor" type="number" min="0" max="9999">
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="produto-y" class="linha-produto">
      Produto Y:
      <select name="produto-y" class="seletor-produto" required>
        <option disabled selected value> -- Selecione uma opção -- </option>
        <option value="SIM">SIM</option>
        <option value="NÃO">NÃO</option>
      </select>

      <div class="valor-produto">
        VALOR INTENSE: 
        <input name="produto-y_valor" type="number" min="0" max="9999">
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

jQuery pode até parecer simples de fazer algo, porém conforme sua aplicação/página for crescendo, vai ficando cada vez mais difícil dar manutenção.

Eu sugiro fortemente você dar uma olhada no [Vuejs](https://br.vuejs.org/) pois é um framework js simples e fácil de aprender. Diferente de [React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/) ou [Angular](https://angular.io/) você não precisa configurar nenhum ambiente de desenvolvimento, você conseguirá iniciar seu desenvolvimento semelhante ao jQuery, importando o framework com `<script src="..."></script>` e abrindo outra tag `<script>` para poder programar sua página.

Ai você pode aos poucos aprendendo e evoluindo sua página para uma aplicação e conforme vai aprendendo vai tornando-a mais sofisticada, passando a usar ferramentas para fazer build, rotas para outras páginas e etc...

O mais importante é que você acabará escrevendo menos do que com jQuery usando componentes e tendo de escrever menos para interagir entre javascript e html para tornar sua aplicação dinâmica de verdade.

Comment: Eu entendi sobre o class, vou alterar meu código e dou retorno posteriormente. Muito obrigado desde já. Ah, Não consegui compreender o Vuejs de cara, mas vou pesquisar um pouco mais. Aprendi muito do bootstrap nesse [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/alerts/), e me ajudou muito a compreender os usos. Vou ver se acho algo similar do Vuejs.

Comment: Devia ter enviado o link da versão br ja, desculpa
https://br.vuejs.org/

Comment: Deu certo a sua resposta, agora vou tratar as exceções e trabalhar com os vários itens que tenho que relacionar. Obrigado.